# Contact names not showing for the calls and messages

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, contacts

My Galaxy S3 was working great until I installed a firmware update on 26/11/12. Immediately after, the names dropped off the calls and messages and it is now showing phone numbers only. When I dial somebody or receive an incoming call, only the numbers are displayed not the contact name.

Please help....

Comment: could you please make sure your contacts data are still there?

Comment: I agree with the sentiments of @ss1271, it seems like perhaps your phone is no longer associated with your google account that most likely contains all of your contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with GF's phone. The problem was caused by an update. There are talks of a possible fix on [Vodafone.com.au forum](http://community.vodafone.com.au/t5/Android-Phones-and-Tablets/Samsung-Galaxy-S3-Jelly-bean-update-issue/td-p/165862) via upgrade but the simplest solution, instead of waiting for fix (which may never come to all carriers), is to do a factory reset.

Make sure to make a backup of your phone before doing it because everything will be gone.
Step-by-step for factory reset is [available here](http://droidlessons.com/how-to-factory-reset-the-samsung-galaxy-s3/).